# How to get JSON data from php and display into textview in android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, json

Im making an android program that will display data on textviews based on JSON from a php webpage.

Here is a sample of my JSON that is already displayed on the php page:

```
[{"ID":"1","temperature":"33","max_humidity":"33","min_humidity":"34","lowtide":"35","hightide":"35","sunrise":"500","sunset":"530","moonrise":"530","moonset":"540","illumination":"45%"}]
```

I want to one of my textview to display "Temperature: 33", etc..

I tried getting the source code of my webpage inside my android program using httpclient & string buffer, then parsing only the JSON texts then pass to a variable, but that doesnt work for me.  I need the webpage because my database is there (which is the source of my JSON)

Is there any very easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, here is what you need. No need of third parties library.

```
try{
    String jsonStr = getFromWeb(); // jsonStr = {"ID":"1","temperature":"33","max_humidity":"33","min_humidity":"34","lowtide":"35","hightide":"35","sunrise":"500","sunset":"530","moonrise":"530","moonset":"540","illumination":"45%"}]
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
        String temperature = obj.getString("temperature");
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourtextviewid);
        tv.setText("Temperature: " + temperature);
    }catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thanks! i've been searching for days but this neat code works for me! :)

Comment: Glad to help. Please upvote and mark this as an answer.

Comment: sure! as soon as i'll receive 15 reputation score ill upvote because now i cant :)

Comment: Okay. I have upvoted your question . you have +5 reps.

Answer (score 0):

Gson is a great library for parsing json: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/