# ANDROID - How to display MySql table(json encode from .php) into textview

Tags: php, mysql, json, android-studio

can someone tell me how to display value of "ASK" table below,
I've been looking for references to solve the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794578/how-to-get-json-data-from-php-and-display-into-textview-in-android) , and [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/),
but i'm not yet solved the problem

> here is the result of json encode

```
[{"id":"1","ask":"pertanyaan ke 1"},{"id":"2","ask":"pertanyaan ke 2"},{"id":"3","ask":"pertanyaan ke 3"},{"id":"4","ask":"pertanyaan ke 4"},{"id":"5","ask":"pertanyaan ke 5"}]
```

> MainActivity

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try{
            String jsonStr = "http://zxccvvv.cuccfree.com/send_data.php";
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
            String pertanyaan= obj.getString("pertanyaan");
            tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_json);
            tv.setText("pertanyaan: " + pertanyaan);
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

did i missing somethings?
any idea to solve guys?

Comment: What you've missed is making a HTTP request. All you do is storing an URL as a string and then convert it to a JSON object. You never call that URL to get the results.

Comment: i think i did it at "JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(**jsonStr**);" or maybe i did a wrong code to call the  URL?

Comment: Simon is right, and also what library are you using to parse the JSON content ? Volley ?

Comment: i didn't use 3rd party lib, i just try what @Lazy Ninja answer [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794578/how-to-get-json-data-from-php-and-display-into-textview-in-android)

Comment: @MegaColorBoy what article sir?

Comment: @Flix: Sorry, my bad, here's the link: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/